# Segue Error in detail view controller

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I have created the model class and with some static images and text I have populated the UICollectionView, but when the user touches the cell it shows an error in view controller 2 when I print or show it on a label. Below is the code.

Any suggestion?!

This is the model class

```
import Foundation

class Pokemon {
    private var  _name: String!
    private var _pokedexId: Int!

    // Setter And Getter
    var name : String {
        return _name
    }

    var pokedexId: Int {
        return _pokedexId
    }

    // Initializer to initialize the data
    init(name : String, pokedexId: Int) {
        self._name = name
        self._pokedexId = pokedexId
    }
}
```

This is segue func in viewcontroller 1

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
if segue.identifier == "pokeSegue" {
    if let detailVC = segue.destinationViewController as? ViewController2 {
        if let poke = sender as? Pokemon {
            detailVC.pokemon = poke
        }
    }
}
```

UICollectionView delegate

```
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let poke: Pokemon!
    if inSearchMode {
        poke = filteredPokemon[indexPath.row]
    } else  {
        poke = pokemon[indexPath.row]
    }
    print(poke.name)
    performSegueWithIdentifier("pokeSegue", sender: self)
}
```

In viewController2

```
import UIKit
class ViewController2: UIViewController {

    var pokemon: Pokemon!
    var receviceingString : String!

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

      print(pokemon.name) //unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
    }

}
```

Comment: Hint: sender is not a Pokemon but a type of UIView.

Comment: @Raphael Sir thank you for your rlp but can you elaborate becoz Pokemon name is a class

Comment: The test `let poke = sender as? Pokemon` is always `false` because the `sender` argument of `prepareForSegue` is the UIView / control that triggered the segue.

Comment: Print the sender in `prepareForSegue` to see the type. As Raphaël hinted it's probably not  a `Pokemon` object. Side-note: what tutorial suggests those stupid backing private variables to create read-only properties? In Swift just declare a property as constant (let) to get the same functionality and get rid of the private variables.

Comment: @vadian Sir its printing the correct value which i want to pass it to the viewcontroller2 but as soon as the viewcontroler2 is loaded it give the fatal error Any Suggestion..!!

Comment: @kk002able Put a breakpoint in `prepareForSegue` and see step by step what is happening and what value is given to `detailVC.pokemon`.

Comment: @raphael Sir As you have said the line ie let poke = sender as?Pokemon returning false but cannot figure it out how to solve..

Comment: I have perform the segue in "didSelectItemAtIndexPath" and tried to print the required value which i want to send and it prints the correct one and further in prepare for segue i tried to send but error is what am i getting when second view is loaded

Comment: Can you add the code of this method to your question ?

Comment: If `as? Pokemon` returns false then *it's **not** printing the correct value*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

Use `poke` as the sender instead of `self` when calling `performSegueWithIdentifier` :

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("pokeSegue", sender: poke)
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

I assume that you are using an `UICollectionViewCell` to trigger the segue.

If so, the `let poke = sender as? Pokemon` will always returns `false` and be skipped because the `sender` will be the `UICollectionViewCell` that triggered the segue and not an instance of `Pokemon`.

You can either create a new type of `UICollectionViewCell` that can store a Pokemon object or simply use the `tag` property of the cells to store the index of the referenced Pokemon.

This value is configurable from the `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` method.

Then in the `prepareForSegue` method you have to cast the sender object to the relevant `UICollectionView` type and retrieve the Pokemon with the information you defined.